# Можно ли выделить такой корень?

Tags: морфемика

Можно ли в слове ***"отведать"*** выделить корень **"отвед",** если имеется в виду значение *"вкушать что-либо"*. Странно было бы трактовать данное слово с помощью слова "ведать" пищу.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146649/discussion-on-question-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Ничего странного, потому что слово от "ведать" - "познать". Вкушать - от слова укус, кусать, искушение, хотя это отдельная тема. А вы знаете что такое душа в конце концов? Или этимологию слов, например, гомо сапиенс?

Comment: То есть я бы перефразировал ваш вопрос в "почему слово ведать и кусать, вкушать имеют сходные семантические значения?"

Comment: @oleedd а что думаете насчет слова "отставать" (не в значении отчаливать)

Comment: Не ощущаю приставку, но они меняются... "Ста" не несёт отчётливого смысла. Для него надо, чтобы было связанное по смыслу слово без приставки. Нельзя сказать, что "отстал" и "стал" (*стал ровно*) близкие по смыслу слова.

Comment: @oleedd В новом словаре Тихонова этого слова вообще почему-то нет, хотя в старом они находятся в разных смысловых группах (там корни не написаны), Значит, "отста" бы выделили?

Comment: Ещё играет роль сама приставка, "от" имеет довольно сильное влияние. Играет роль глубина корня. Если самый поверхностный, то "отста", а они смотрят глубже.

Comment: вы не найдете в новых словарях почему это так, потому что новые словари пишут буратины. @oleedd "Ст" - это остановка, стоп, стой, встал, стоять, отстал - стал отдельно, отделился, отбился от движения в результате остановки.

Comment: @Буратино Может, ещё значение одной буквы разбирать? Отстал — это не стал отдельно, это не успел за другими.

Comment: @oleedd нет, буквы бывают, но не все. Буква О используется в качестве символа завершенности, целостности. Но я бы в буквицу не лез. я не гений настолько). Отстал - это стоит когда други идут. Нет никакого конфликта значения.

Есть приставка - протокорень раз, например, она до 1 буквы не сокращается. Еще есть проблема, что в церковнославянском не было гласных, одни согласные

Comment: @oleedd и дело скорее не в буквах, а то что приставки произошли от сокращений или наоборот.

Comment: "Отстал — это не стал отдельно, это не успел за другими." - это опаздавший, от корня поздь, pas, past и др - другое совсем слово.

Comment: @oleedd вот, например, погуглил слово имя-name оказалось все забавнее. Что этот корень много где в английский в том числе словах.

вот люди занимаются языком, в вы все семантику мацаете:
https://www.etymonline.com/word/*no-men-?ref=etymonline_crossreference

https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/nama

Comment: @Буратино Опоздавший — это тот, кто пришёл позже, он не действовал вместе с другими.

Comment: @oleedd Нет, как раз наоборот, опоздавший, тот кто past - живет прошлым, идет за другими последним. А отставший - отделившийся, может он вообще потерялся и пошел в другую сторону, но факт что вышли вместе а пришли раздельно. А опоздавший это "хотели" прийти вместе - и пришли вместе, но с разны интервалом, хотя вышли одновременно. То есть опоздавший - это как раз занимающийся одним делом с другими, а отставший - это отделившийся и занявшийся чем то другим. Ты почему опоздал? - Я спешил, но меня задержали.. Ты почему отстал? - Ну я увидел по пути такое интересное.. - занялся другим делом.

Comment: @oleedd не отставай, а то опоздаешь/опоздаем - не тоже самое, что не опаздывай, а то отстанешь. Отстать - это про что-то фактическое, физическое отделение. А опоздать - это про проекции прошлого. * там выше ошибка, вышли не одновременно, вышли в разное время, но хотели прийти в одно. То есть опоздавший - это нарушивший проекцию будущего на настоящее. В этом плане слово отстать, стоять - гораздо более просто и физическое, чем замороченное позд/пост - связанное с долгом или обещанием будущего.

Comment: @Буратино Обычно отстают из-за того, что не успевают, не хватает скорости. Обычно это как бы постепенный процесс (например, отстал во время диктовки, отстал во время забега).

Comment: @oleedd отстают по-разному, отстал - отделился, стал отдельным. Какая причина - не известно, может нет причины, может причина не сочетается с целью похода, может еще почему. Так же не известно время. То есть ни модальности, ни хронологии. А опоздал - там четкая и цель, и хронология. Смотри на часы - ты опоздал на урок, а не отстал от урока. Отстающий вовсе не потому что неуспевающий. Отстань от меня - отойди, стань в стороне, не будь со мной. Просто ты ориентируешь на забеги, но это слово не только в соревнованиях и играх употребляется и даже не употребляется. Говорят последний,а не отсталый.

Comment: Отстают без причины, отстать - это уже причина сама по себе. А опаздывают почему-то. 

*От ворон отстала, а к павам не пристала.* *Чтоб к людям не пристать, и от людей не отстать.**Не штука отстать, а штука догонять!* и тд. Даль. - отстать - причина, а не штука, а следствие - догонять нужно.

Comment: @oleedd Даль почему приводит пословицы ? потому что именно они показывают разницу в смысле слов, а не разницу в значениях. Кстати, в английском языке и латыни практически нет пословиц. Потому что в английском языке почти нет таких простых слов, которые уже причина. Смысл - это связь с причинностью, а значение можно любое выдумать. Не всякое приживется правда, но часть может стать Сленгом. Сленг - это эвфемизмы и термины, которые смысла не несут никакого, только значения. А Жаргон - это просто диалект, редкие слова, но сохраняющие смысл - связь с причиной через корень и образ в нем заключенный.

Comment: @oleedd подскажите, еще такой момент. Ученик выделил в слове "продавец" корень "прода", я вижу здесь корень "да" ( не соглашусь с Тихоновым) в выделении корня "прода". Вы что думаете?

Comment: Должны быть слова без приставки. "Дать" далёкое по смыслу. Не вижу здесь стандартного влияния приставки "про" (приставки меняют смысл сопоставимо с другими случаями). Вы видите более глубокий корень — этимологический.

Comment: @oleedd понятно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, еще по поводу слова "отменить". мне кажется, что здесь нет корня "мен".

Comment: Вас можно понять. С одной стороны, нет прямой связи с "менять", а с другой — ощущаю здесь как бы стандартное влияние приставки, но удалось найти лишь одно слово с таким значением приставки — "отозвать".

Comment: @oleedd почему-то все словари в один голос твердят, что здесь именно корень "мен".

Comment: Это хорошо, плохо, когда разнобой. Как сказано выше, приставка "от" имеет сильное влияние, она неохотно желает входить в корень (здесь есть предпосылки).

Comment: @oleedd согласитесь, что отменить  - это не то же самое, что заменить, сменить, подменить. Значение этой "от" уже затемняется.

Comment: Да, выше уже согласился. Только затемняется значение "мен".